# Strange CSS issue on Android Chrome CSS not applying when using jquery load

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, google-chrome

i have created a website using bootstrap css framework, it works as it should be in desktop chrome, firefox, IE browsers. Mobile stock browser works fine too.

but issue is only with Mobile Chrome browser.

On contents page, there are comments, which gets loaded after page loads, something like this in javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function (){if ($('#loadComments').length ) {reloadComments();}});

function reloadComments(id) {
$('#loadComments').load('/load_comments.php?id='+ id); 
}
```

everything else is working great, but the content which is loaded using .load jquery function , doesnt follow CSS rules.

and only those looks bigger than normal page. even though all other page contents are smaller in size, the loaded contents are very bigger.

how can i fix this ?

update:::

its not just for jquery .load ,
its happening for bootstrap `nav nav-tabs`

e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/4g9pw5mo/

if i try to click other nav tabs and then come back to original tabs the font size gets increased,

but its not replicating the issue on jsfiddle.net and mobile chrome.,
so i guess, its have something to do with my CSS.

Comment: There's something fishy going on. Maybe that part of the DOM looks different on the mobile browsers. Try inspecting that part of your page using Chrome remote debugger: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: just noticed its not just the .load, but its happeing to the nav nav-tabs of bootstrap, let me edit the quetion with more details., thanks

Comment: I am using jquery UI, jquery mobile and jPlayer and this is happening with my ajax loaded playlist items.